# Copy Row into new sheet when criteria met

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to find a solution on how to copy rows from one sheet in excel to another when a certain criteria is met. I have tried other macros/solutions posted here with no avail.

The data that I would like to copy into a new sheet is in row GG and is text "Passed with flying colors". It is found in a sheet called SchoolEast

I would like for it to copy the entire row from A to GH when this phrase is found in a cell in column GG in the dataset. The target sheet is called PassedFC.

Would love to get some help with this. Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: `I have tried other macros/solutions posted here with no avail` Please post the one that got you the closest and tell us what errors are happening when you run the code.  Post the code in the original post using edit.  Do not use comments to post code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty simple VBA routine, but I totally get how tricky it is to wrap your head around this stuff when your first starting out. Below I have an untested subroutine that should get you like 99% of the way there. I made copious comments to help out.

```
Sub copyWhenCriteriaIsMet()
    Dim shFrom as worksheet, shTo as worksheet
    Dim rngReadCell as Range, rngRead as Range
    Dim intWriteRow as integer


    'Change shFrom to the sheet name we are reading and shTo to the sheet we are writing to
    set shFrom = Sheets("Sheet1")
    set shTo = Sheets("Sheet2")

    'Change this to fit the range we are reading
    set rngRead = shFrom.Range("GG1:GG5000")

    'Set the initial row to which we are writing the found data
    'Inside the For loop below we will increase this by one whenever we write a new line
    intWriteRow = 1

    'Now loop through each cell in the range using a "For" loop
    For Each rngReadCell in rngRead.Cells
        'Everything happening between "For" and "Next" is done over and over again for each cell
        'We can reference the Cell that is being read as it will be automatically stored in 
        'variable "rngReadCell"

        'Use an "IF" statement to test if the value in rngReadCell says "Passed with flying colors"
        If rngReadCell.Value = "Passed with flying colors" 'note this is case sensitive here in VBA
            'Everything happening between "If" and "End IF" only happens if that conditions is true

            'Copy the contents of rngReadCell's Row (between Column A and GH) to the other sheet
            'There are a few ways to reference this A:GH range, I'm going to use "RANGE()" and concatenate
            'since that's the easier to understand than .offset().resize() or .Row().Range()
            shFrom.Range("A" & rngReadCell.row & ":GH" & rngReadCell.row).copy Destination:=shTo.Range("A" & intWriteRow)

            'Now that we wrote that line out, lets increment the intWriteRow variable
            intWriteRow = intWriteRow + 1

        End IF

        'Nothing else to do here, so this will loop back to the top of the For loop and test the next
        'rngReadCell.Value
    Next rngReadRow
End Sub
```